# Uniform handle parameter for multiple datatypes in C

Tags: c, struct, unions

This is in C. I have a handle which I use throughout many files (let's call it `type_handle`), which is an `enum` presently, but currently I would need to extend it to support a typedef-ed struct (called `my_type`) as well. Since many functions take `type_handle` as an input parameter, I don't want to change the design majorly so that I need to redo all the files. So my idea is to pass `int`, `float`, `double` and then `my_type`. I want to have some sort of a `union` function of all types I want, so that I don't need to modify functions taking `type_handle`. How should I design this?

```
typedef enum
{
    INT  = MPI_INT,
    INT8 = MPI_INT8_T,
    INT16 = MPI_INT16_T
}
types_t;

typedef union {
    my_type dtype;
    types_t etype;
} type_handle;
```

I want to design this in a way such that `any_func(type_handle type)` could accept `any_func(INT)` as well as `any_func(dtype)` where dtype is say a derived datatype of type `my_type`.

Comment: Did you try it? Which problems did you face?

Comment: @alk I was thinking of designing in a way such that I could mention `type_handle` (a superset of types) in function signature/definitions, but actually pass `type_handle.dtype` or `type_handle.etype` during runtime. But I guess that is not allowed/possible for good reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `union` in C you need some way to know which member to use.  C itself cannot tell you which element of your `union` is the one you assigned.  This will be confusing to explain, since you are already dealing with types, but the idiom would be:

```
struct {
   what_is_in_the_union_t what;
   union {
       type_a a;
       type_b b;
       ...
   } u;
};
```

Where `what_is_in_the_union_t` is your own enum of `{ TYPE_A, TYPE_B, ... }`.  As I said, this will expand in a confusing way in your example because your inner `type_a` is already a `types_t`.

Comment: if this will cause some issues when use different compiler option like `-enum_is_int`?

Comment: From the OP's posting I understand, that which member of the union is used is implcitly defined by which functions is called. Will say: The functions knows what it is expected to receive.

Comment: @HowChen: This is not C++, so we are not dealing with (compiler supplied) polymorphism here.  I think the OP wants to implement something similar in C manually.

Comment: @alk Sorry if the post is does not make it clear, but in my case any function, `any_func` should handle enums as well as `my_type`, as I have no way to segregate. @BenJackson yes, I have to implement polymorphism behavior.

Comment: @Sayan: Your question isn't unclear, I simply did not read it to the end and therefore overlooked the use case around `any_func()`. Sry!